# Ruby ActiveRecord fundamentals : appending an object to an array with << might update its attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I just noticed that one of the attributes of an object was being updated when this object was appended to an array. This behavior looks very surprising to me and I thought I might be missing something fundamental about ActiveRecord.

In my app, every idea has a father (through its father_id attribute). This association is set in models/idea.rb with the following :

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Idea" # , :foreign_key => "idea_id"
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "father_id", :dependent => :destroy

  [...]
```

Here is what happens in rails console :

I first select a given idea :

```
irb(main):003:0> n = Idea.find(1492)
  Idea Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "ideas".* FROM "ideas" WHERE "ideas"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1492]]
=> #<Idea id: 1492, father_id: 1407, [...]>
```

I then retrieve its children through the associations :

```
irb(main):004:0> c = n.children
  Idea Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "ideas".* FROM "ideas" WHERE "ideas"."father_id" = 1492
=> []
```

It doesn't have any, which is ok.
I then want to append the idea itself to the 'c' variable but this triggers an unwanted  UPDATE action in the database :

```
irb(main):005:0> c << n
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.9ms)  UPDATE "ideas" SET "father_id" = 1492, "updated_at" = '2013-12-06 12:57:25.982619' WHERE "ideas"."id" = 1492
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> [#<Idea id: 1492, father_id: 1492, [...]>]
```

The father_id attribute, which had the value 1407 now has the value 1492, i.e. the idea's id.

Can anyone explain me why this happens and how I can create an array that includes an object's children and the object itself without altering the object's attributes ?

NB : I'm using ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. You're adding a new idea to the set of ideas belonging to a specific father. This happens because it's not an array you're appending to, it's an ActiveRecord association. In your console, try `n.children.class`.

If you want a flat array which won't modify objects appended to it, you want:

```
c = n.children.to_a

c << n
```

Comment: Many thanks @meagar. I realize that ActiveRecord is even more "active" than I thought...

Comment: your solution does work but I actually tried n.children.class and the console gives the following : "=> Array", just like if I do c = n.children.to_a and then c.class. Do you know how one could clearly show that n.children and n.children.to_a are not the same kind ?